# Devuan as a rolling release?

Tags: debian, devuan, rolling-release

Is it possible to get Devuan Linux as a rolling release?

All I can download seem to be the Jessie and ASCII releases, but I cannot find a link to Beowulf and Ceres.

Can Ceres be defined a rolling release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can Ceres be defined a rolling release?

Devuan Ceres is the unstable suite ( Sid), it is a [cyclic-rolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_distribution#Cyclic-rolling_distributions) distribution.

> Is it possible to get Devuan Linux as a rolling release?

Install the ascii then edit your [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://devuan.org/os/etc/apt/sources.list) , change the codename from `ascii` to `ceres` or `unstable`.

From:

```
deb http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged ascii main  
deb http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged ascii-updates main 
deb http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged ascii-security main
```

to

```
deb http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged unstable main
```

or

```
deb http://pkgmaster.devuan.org/merged ceres main
```

Then run:

```
apt update && apt dist-upgrade
```