# How to install Devuan/Debian testing/unstable without starting from a stable release?

Tags: kernel, system-installation, development

It is possible to install Devuan/Debian stable and then editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` upgrade to a testing/unstable branch ([ref](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509100/devuan-as-a-rolling-release)).

However on my laptop I have an AMD Ryzen 7 2700U processor, which does not support Linux kernels before 4.10, so I just cannot install the stable versions (kernel 4.9) to start from.

Where can I download from and install the latest unstable versions (e.g. Devuan Ceres) directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list.d/devuan-ceres.list

deb     http://deb.devuan.org/merged ceres main

deb-src http://deb.devuan.org/merged ceres main
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how dangerously you want to live you can install Devuan daedalus. However as far as I understand that's more unstable than unstable: it's development. That means sometimes 100+ package updates daily.

Here are installers: https://files.devuan.org/devuan_daedalus/installer-iso/

I don't understand why there is no installer folder for ceres (equals to Debian sid), because that's what I'd want.

As far as Debian sid goes there are several methods. Three main ways: https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Debian-sid

1. Upgrade a stable install (outside of your question)
2. Image http://cloud.debian.org/images/cloud/sid/daily/latest/debian-sid-nocloud-amd64-daily.raw
3. Install from a Live CD

Comment: The nocloud debian sid (2nd option) was no bueno for me because it is mainly geared for cloud install I guess and was missing a ton of packages, I wanted more out of the box. I ended up going by the stable install route and then dist upgrade. Just like with ceres I cannot fathom why the F there's no regular install iso for sid. It's just stupid. So many people are looking for it, why should we go through all the hoops with the stable?